# Mat Table:-How to get one particular element of a particular row on a button click in Mat table angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Here is my **Datatable.component.html** I want to fetch the one particular item of a row let say "email" of a user in Table. How I can do this?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div class="search-div">
  <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/auth/signup">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Create
  </button>
  <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"*ngIf="searchKey"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="listData"  matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Full Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.firstName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Email</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Mobile</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phoneNum}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>City</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.city}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="LastName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>LastName</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.lastName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="ondisbale(userId)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
        Loading data...
      </mat-footer-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
        No data.
      </mat-footer-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':listData!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
    <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;background-color:ivory; padding:1rem; border-top-left-radius: 2rem; border-top-right-radius: 2rem;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-instagram" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px; color: orchid"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-twitter" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px; color: royalblue"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-reddit" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 10px; color:orangered;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
          Copyright @2019 All rights reserved
        </div>
      </div>
```

I don't know how to get it.Basically I added the button Delete_outline. Now on click it i want to get email of a partcular row which I have clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `row` object will contain the values of that particular row. You can send the email by passing it from `row` to the `ondisable()` function on the `(click)` event of the `delete_outline` button.

```
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="ondisable(row.email)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
```